# Flow collect observed data changes multiple times from background to foreground app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I have used Kotlin flow for API call. In viewModel expose stateFlow to activity to observe data changes.

When I launch app, API is hit, get data and collect flow in Activity successfully.

***Issue is when I keep my app in background and open after 5 seconds API is hit again. I don't want to hit API again because I already collect flow.***

Can anyone help, how can achieve the desired behavior?

ViewModel:

```
class FlowViewModel(
    dataSource: DataSource
) : BaseViewModel<UiState>() {

    val priceFlow: StateFlow<UiState> = dataSource
        .apiCall
        .onStart {
            Timber.tag("Flow").d("Flow has started.")
        }
        .map { stockList ->
            UiState.Success(list) as UiState
        }
        .onCompletion {
            Timber.tag("Flow").d("Flow has completed.")
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            initialValue = UiState.Loading,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(stopTimeoutMillis = 5000)
        )
}
```

Collecting flow in Activity like below:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.priceFlow.collect { uiState ->
                    render(uiState)
                }
            }
        }
```

Cannot add whole dataSource class here I added mock DataSource for reference.

```
class DataSource(mockApi: MockApi) : BaseDataSource {

    override val apiCall: Flow<List<Price>> = flow {
            val currentStockList = mockApi.getCurrentPrices()
            emit(currentStockList)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your DataStore implementation please?

Comment: @MaNDOOoo dataSource contain API call only. For reference add sample DataSource that looks similar to original one.

Answer (score 2):

Use savedStateHandle to persist data for UI elements during proccess death and check their value before making an API call. Use the init block for this purpose.

ViewModel:

```
class FlowViewModel(
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    dataSource: DataSource
) : BaseViewModel<UiState>() {

private val _uiState: MutableStateFlow<UiState?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
val uiState = _uiState.asStateFlow()
val priceFlow = savedStateHandle.getStateFlow("priceFlow", emptyList<String>())

init {
  if(priceFlow.value.isEmpty()){
    callApi()
  }
}

fun callApi(){
  viewModelScope.launch {
    _uiState.emit(dataSource.apiCall())
  }
}

fun updatePrice(priceList: List<String>){
  savedStateHandle["priceFlow"] = priceList
}
}
```

Activity:

```
val priceList = viewModel.priceFlow.collectAsState().value

lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            viewModel.uiState.collect { uiState ->
                when(uiState){
                   is UiState.Success -> {
                      viewModel.updatePrice(uiState.data)
                   }
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. This is one way to solve this problem but Is there anything in Kotlin Flow that take care that flow has been collected so no need of API call.